# How do you use a var declared in directive, inside an element in the directive's template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes, angularjs-scope

Essentially, I want this to work:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
     var someObj = {"shout": "Yodelayheehoo"};

     return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: "<my-special-directive my-obj="someObj"></my-special-directive>"
     }
});
```

I want `mySpecialDirective` to receive the object defined in `myDirective` but it is not.

What is the syntax (if any) to make this work?

Comment: Need add to scope of directive in the link function to work

Answer (score 0):

When you make a directive you can create a link function (Make all the logic of the directive), and the first parameter of that function is the scope of the directive. Then you need add the variable into that scope to access inside the directive.

```js
var app = angular.module('asd', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
     var someObj = {"shout": "Yodelayheehoo"};

     return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: "<my-special-directive my-obj='someObj'>{{someObj}}</my-special-directive>",
          link:function(scope) {
            scope.someObj = someObj;
          }
          
     }
});
```

```html
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
 
  <body ng-app="asd">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
  </body>
```

Comment: Mm maybe the another directive is not transclude and remove the content, change my-special-directive in template to a div and see if show the value